# Should I remove the 2x4 between the joists of this deck?

Tags: framing, deck

I'm working on replacing the decking on an existing deck. While removing the old decking, I came across something I've not seen before. I've seen decks framed as illustrated below, where members are attached to posts to allow joists to be hung.

[image]

(*This likely isn't a code approved method of building a deck anymore, but I'm not rebuilding the entire deck to fix it.*)

The thing I don't understand, is that they added a 2x4 laid on its face between the two beams.

[image]

I'm not sure why they added the 2x4, maybe to stiffen up the "*beam*", or just as a nailing surface.  Unfortunately, it works great at trapping water under the decking. All the decking that was in this area is rotten, and the whole area is damp (despite not having rain in about a week).

I've never seen a "*beam*" built in this way, and I'm a bit perplexed. Can I remove the 2x4, so that water is not being trapped?  Is it there for some structural reason?

Comment: Can't answer the structural question, but if you want to keep it, why not make it flush with the top edge of the ledgers to shed most of the water? And a few weep holes wouldn't hurt.

Comment: It is flush with the top of the beams, but since it's a 6 1/2" flat spot, it still holds water. I thought about weep holes, but I'm afraid the holes will cause the 2x4 to rot more quickly.

Comment: A bit of copper tubing hammered into the hole might help.

Comment: @bib Any problem using copper in contact with PT lumber?

Comment: Don't know. I know steel and galv is a problem.

Comment: The 2x4 can easily be replaced with 3-1/2" long spacers, cut from the same dimensional stock at the joists, and toe-nailed into place.  Though I'm not sure what the function of the 2x4 was, what the dims. of the joists are, or why there aren't joist hangers.  It all sounds a bit suspect to me.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason for that board, but a photo would help clear things up. I also assume that the joists are hung on the beam using standard steel hangers and approved fasteners. If all that is correct, you should be able to remove the board.

I'd guess that it was added to support decking joints that fell over the beam. Presumably the decking ran parallel to the beam. A better approach would have been to put individual blocks in that essentially carry the joist through the beam gap.

Comment: The beam members are simply nailed to the posts. The joists are attached to the beam members using nails (no hangers). This deck may have been built before hangers were required, or by an individual that didn't know hangers were required. The builder must have built the two sections of deck, by nailing the joists through the beam. Then they attached the beam of the two sections of deck to the posts, by nailing through the beams.  Finally they inserted the 2x4 and nailed it in place.

Comment: Maybe I'll rip it out, and nail in some blocks as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks. FYI, there are no ledgers in this scenario. There are two beam members. Ledgers fasten to a wall. I'd just be sure that the joists are securely fastened so that the beam members can't twist away.

Comment: Only add blocks if your decking needs them, or if you think they'll keep your joist connections tight.

Comment: I was just using the word "ledger", because I wasn't sure what else to call them.  I guess "beam member" is more accurate.  I think the way the decking falls, I will have to add blocking.

Comment: The 2x4 is not structural. However, as you can guess, the "weak link" to this system is the connection of the beams to the posts. If connected by 16d nails, they're only good for about 106 lbs. each. I'd count the number of nails now while the decking is removed, then, next year on your birthday party when everyone is hanging out on the deck, you'll know how many people you can allow out on your deck to sing happy birthday to you.